# how to call jquery from master page in asp.net(vb.net)

Tags: jquery, mysql, asp.net, vb.net

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
            var name = $('#txtname').val();
            var subject = $('#txtsubject').val();
            var body = $('#txtbody').val();
            if (name != '' && subject != '' && body) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "vbcode.aspx/InsertData",
                    data: "{'username':'" + name + "','subj':'" + subject + "','desc':'" + body + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        var obj = data.d;
                        if (obj == 'true') {
                            $('#txtname').val('');
                            $('#txtsubject').val('');
                            $('#txtbody').val('');
                            $('#lblmsg').html("Details Submitted Successfully");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                alert('Please enter all the fields')
                return false;
            }
        })
    });
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
```

this jquery should be called while using master page.but when i use master page it is not working.kindley 
give solution for it.when i run this in ordinary web page it is working.

Comment: can you paste all your JS plugins urls also, so that we can know whether it is a conflicting issue or not.

Comment: do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: Share your aspx code?

Comment: no, no errors, it works in a page that does not refer a master page .if i refer a master page, it doesnt works.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**
If your button is an ASP.net control with `runat="server"` and it has the `ID` set to `btnSubmit` then you should update this line:

```
 $('#btnSubmit').click(function () { ... });
```

with this line:

```
 $('input[id$="btnSubmit"]').click(function () { ... });
```

The explanation is simple: Your HTML button will have and ID like to `ctl01_btnSubmit`, **not** `btnSubmit`. You could get the ID using `btnSubmit.ClientID` but you cannot do this from the master page. You know that will end with `btnSubmit` and that is what `[id$="btnSubmit"]` does: it will select the input element having an `id` that ends with `btnSubmit`.

**Solution 2:** As an alternate solution you could only declare your function in the master page and bind it from your pages/controls like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#<%=btnSubmit.ClientID%>').on("click", function () {
         FunctionFromMasterpage();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add JQuery Library Reference in Your Page. Then Add document.ready in Jquery Function Like below.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function ().........
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add reference to jquery first (ideally in head element) and write jQuery code afterwards. In your case the sequence should be like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#btnSubmit').click(function(){
//your code goes here
});
</script>
```